# Papers or book that address the value vs. reference distinction across programming languages?

Tags: memory, reference, copy, computer-science, bibliography

I'm seeking academic texts that dig into the value vs. reference topic (aka reference semantics and value semantics) from a general and historical perspective, not focusing on just one programming language (there is a lot written about C++, for instance, but I'm interested in getting an across-like perspective).

Can you think of any?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main topic you are probably interested in is the invention of "pointers", who actually gave rise to the distinction between shallow copies and deep copies, non-existent before it (for example, in the early versions of FORTRAN). There is a lot written about this. For instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming). Good luck with your quest!